# Dyamic menu links how to

Tags: drupal

I have a menu block to the right of my content area. I want to be able to click on one of the links and have the content in the content area change, whether that be to advance a nodeque to the matching content type or just diplay a block containing that one content type.

I would usually do this with php, by adding a url variable site.com/data?uid=somenumber to display the data i want on the same page. I don't want to have to create multiple content pages to do this. There has to be a way that the links that are created and displayed in the menu block can just change the content inside the view displayed on the page.

Im a total drupal newb. So any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your content area is displaying a view, you can definitely do this using views arguments.  So, for example, if you want the menu links to vary the view content based on different terms, you can set up your view to expect an argument from the url.

To set it up:

1. Add a 'Contextual filter' to your view (under the 'Advanced' section)
2. In my example below, I've added 'region' as my contextual filter, which is just a term reference on my content type
3. When configuring the contextual filter, set it up such that when the filter is not present in the URL, it just displays all values (that's the default) -- shown in screenshot.
  4.

This way, when you first load the page, and no menu item has been selected, all your content will show in the view.  Now you'll have to set up your menus to provide the argument, and your view should react appropriately!

Let me know if that works or if you have any questions.

[image]